# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '−4.0'

Tags: python

Why is:

```
print([float(a.get_text()) for a in cb.ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()])
```

giving me:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '−4.0'
```

where cb is an instance of [ColorBar](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html)

Comment: That seems to be the [unicode minus sign `−`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2212), not the [hyphen-minus `-`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+002D) that is normally used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pasting your text:

```
>>> a = "−4.0"
>>> ord(a[0])
8722
>>> ord("-")
45
>>>
```

You've pasted the "wrong" hypen/minus character (some alternate slightly longer unicode one) in your code or interface. Python isn't able to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

Try `str.replace("−", "-")`

**Ex:**

```
print(float('−4.0'.replace("−", "-")))
```

**Output:**

```
-4.0
```